# document on load does not work but window on load does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my script to run only after my entire page has loaded included the pictures.

So I have been using this code.

```
$(document).on('load', function() { $('#loading').hide(); });
```

This does not work, since it never activates. However, when I use window instead of document then it works, but its not what I need. I need everything including pictures to be loaded before activating.

I'm very confused why this does not work.

**EDIT**

THis is not a basic onload document, vs document ready question. My pictures are are not fully loaded even when this code loads.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ $('#loading').hide(); });
```

Comment: `I need everything including pictures to be loaded before activating.`  Then use `$(window)` because that's its functionality

Comment: $(window) is activating before all the pictures are shown on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `document` `load` event.  The `load` event occurs on the `window` object.

There is a `DOMContentReady` event on the `document` which occurs at a different time than the window `load` event.

Since you want all resources to be loaded, what you want the window `load` event like  this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
    $('#loading').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I'm finding that sometimes the pictures aren't fully loaded when that function activates.

Comment: @JPFoster - are the pictures you're waiting for coming from `<img>` tags in the HTML source of the page?  Or are they part of some content that is added to the page via Javascript?

Comment: They are <img> tags. I'd also note that they are locally stored. But they are relatively large and takes time to show.

Comment: I think it's because their stored locally and are large files. I think once it gets on a server it will be fine. It works!